# If statement that assigns a variable a string value

Tags: xquery

I am new to XQuery and struggling to find anything online that teaches me simple stuff like this. I am trying to just pass in 2 strings, where 1 string is returned as the tag and 1 string is returned as a new value. So far I have this, but am getting build errors.

```
declare function util:format-promo-tracking-element(
$fieldName as xs:string, 
$stringValue as xs:string)
{
    let $elementName := $fieldName
    if($stringValue = '5.00') then (
    let $stringValue := '4.05'

    return
        element {$elementName}
        {
            data($stringValue) 
        }  

    )
     else()   

};
```

I have tried moving the return statement to the end as well.

Comment: What kind of build issues are you getting, could you add those to the post?

Answer (score 2):

XQuery is an functional language so trying to assign a new value to an existing variable is not allowed.
I think you want something like this.

```
declare function util:format-promo-tracking-element(
$fieldName as xs:string, 
$stringValue as xs:string)
{
let $newValue := if ($stringValue = '5.00') then  '4.05' else $stringValue

    return
        element {$fieldName}
        {
            $newValue
        }  
};
```

There are quite a few basic examples on Wikibooks.